# search mysql database via textbox and button and redirect output to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, html

Hi on my masterpage I have a search box contained in it is a textbox (TextBox1.Text) and a button (Button1_Click) both asp controls.

Im trying to figure out how to search my database and retrieve things that may be similar, I have a User table that I would like to search for Users but spelling could be wrong so how do I still return someone if the spelling is wrong if you know what I mean?

So far:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Search Users
    String Search = TextBox1.Text;
    using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=x; Password=x;"))
    {
    cn.Open();
    using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM User WHERE FirstName LIKE '%"+ Search +"%';", cn))
    //not sure if this is correct, will it return anything that is similar to what is typed?       
    Response.Redirect("Search.aspx");
    // dont know how to send this to a listview on another page? 
}
```

}

The other thing im trying to figure out is how I would send that to another page to view in a listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Soundex](http://www.madirish.net/?article=85) or [Levenshtein distance](http://blog.lolyco.com/sean/2008/08/06/search-suggestions-with-mysql-levenshtein-distance/).